# Microsoft Access Cannot Find Table Object

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am currently creating a short VBA script that takes a table from an Access Data Base and exports it to Excel via the "TransferSpreadSheet" method. However, whenever I do so I receive "Run Time Error 3011" which states that "The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object "MonthsOutput".

Below is the relevant format and code sections:

```
Public Sub Run()

OutputFileName = CurrentProject.Path & "\Test5.xls"
TableName = "MonthsOutput"
Call SetExcel(OutputFileName, 1)
Call ExportToExcel(OutputFileName, TableName)
Call MoveData

End Sub

Public Function SetExcel(OutputFileName As String, SheetNumber As Integer)
Set XL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set XLBook = GetObject(OutputFileName)
Set XLSheet = XLBook.Worksheets(SheetNumber)
Set XLSheet2 = XLBook.Worksheets(3)

End Function

Public Function ExportToExcel(OutputFileName As String, TableName As String)

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, TableName, OutputFileName


End Function
```

I was able to resolve this error occasionally by restarting Access, or creating a different Excel file, or creating a different source Access table. This will work for 1-2 runs and then I get the error without changing anything.

Additionally, if I enter the table "MonthsOutput" via the "Design" mode, VBA will return an error that the object is in use by another user. Thus this leads me to believe that it knows the table exists, it just can't use it.

Everything is stored locally on my computer and the Excel file and Access database are in the same folders. I am running Access 2013 and Excel 2013 but I use the ".xls" extenstions for the "acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12" argument. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel is not needed for an export, so try this:

```
Public Sub Run()

    OutputFileName = CurrentProject.Path & "\Test5.xls"
    TableName = "MonthsOutput"
    Call ExportToExcel(OutputFileName, TableName)

End Sub

Public Function ExportToExcel(OutputFileName As String, TableName As String)

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, TableName, OutputFileName

End Function
```

Also, do use the xlsx extension.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It turns out that by removing my Excel object reference it ensured that Excel would not be open. For some reason, whenever the Excel file is open and a TransferSpreadsheet is attempted it will return the 3011 error. Odd, but eh. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Please mark as answered to close the issue.